# NavigationLink in a Section doesn't behave like in a normalView with a simultaneous action

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

I have created a simple View with a NavigationLink in a Section an when the user presses on it, the value of the variable should change and should navigate the next View simultaneously. But it doesn't work like it should. If I press the "Text", the Value changes, but no navigation. If I press the "empty Space" it navigates to the next View, but the value doesn't change.

If I out the NavigationLink in a "normal" View, it does work like it should.

Is there a way to get this working without SubViews?

```
    
    @State private var newValue = -1
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Image(systemName: "globe")
                    .imageScale(.large)
                    .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
                Text("\(newValue)")
                List {
                    Section ("Navigationlink") { 
                        NavigationLink(destination: EmptyView()) {
                            Text("to Emptyview")
                        }.simultaneousGesture(TapGesture().onEnded{
                            newValue = 100
                        })
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
}


struct EmptyView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "globe")
                .imageScale(.large)
                .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
            Text("Hello, world!")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a @State for Navigation to take place, this is needed as a source of truth needs to change(including navigation) in SwiftUI for any View change to happen , you change the @State for newValue so it changes, but you need to do same for NavigationView, also try NavigationStack in place of NavigationView in future , try below code , good luck

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var newValue = -1
    @State private var changeView = false
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
                    VStack {
                        Image(systemName: "globe")
                            .imageScale(.large)
                            .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
                        Text("\(newValue)")
                        List {
                            Section ("Navigationlink") {
                                NavigationLink(destination: EmptyView(), isActive: $changeView) {
                                    Text("to Emptyview")
                                }.simultaneousGesture(TapGesture().onEnded{
                                    newValue = 100
                                    changeView = true
                                })
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
    }
}
```